# No gear in lock screen to change Desktop Environmnet in Fedora 33

Tags: linux, fedora, window-manager, gnome3

Using Fedora 33, which comes with Gnome DE. I'd like to switch to KDE Plasma. I've tried installing it with

```
sudo dnf install @kde-desktop-environment
sudo dnf group install "KDE Plasma Workspaces"
```

It looks like it is installed:

```
$ ls /usr/share/xsessions
gnome-classic.desktop  gnome.desktop  gnome-xorg.desktop  plasma.desktop
```

But when I lock the screen with Super+L or reboot, there is no "cog" anywhere on the password screen to change desktop environment.

I also tried

```
$ switchdesk kde
Desktop now set up to run KDE.
```

to no avail.

```
$ screenfetch
           /:-------------:\          josh@fedora
        :-------------------::        OS: Fedora 
      :-----------/shhOHbmp---:\      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.9.8-200.fc33.x86_64
    /-----------omMMMNNNMMD  ---:     Uptime: 12m
   :-----------sMMMMNMNMP.    ---:    Packages: 2465
  :-----------:MMMdP-------    ---\   Shell: zsh 5.8
 ,------------:MMMd--------    ---:   Resolution: 1366x768
 :------------:MMMd-------    .---:   DE: GNOME 3.38.1
 :----    oNMMMMMMMMMNho     .----:   WM: Mutter
 :--     .+shhhMMMmhhy++   .------/   WM Theme: Nordic
 :-    -------:MMMd--------------:    GTK Theme: Nordic [GTK2/3]
 :-   --------/MMMd-------------;     Icon Theme: Adwaita
 :-    ------/hMMMy------------:      Font: Cantarell 11
 :-- :dMNdhhdNMMNo------------;       Disk: 81G / 597G (14%)
 :---:sdNMMMMNds:------------:        CPU: Pentium Dual-Core T4500 @ 2x 2.3GHz
 :------:://:-------------::          GPU: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset (CTG)
 :---------------------://            RAM: 1982MiB / 2912MiB
```

There are similar questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054845/installed-i3-but-no-windowmanager-choice-present-on-login-gdm-ubuntu-18-04) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001499/no-gear-to-choose-xorg-session), but neither of them help me. TIA!

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/cqged4/using_sddm_why_is_the_login_screen_at_startup/eww300o), "lock screen" and "login screen" aren't the same thing. The lock screen is handled by the desktop environment, every time the session is locked (by the user or an idle timeout) during the session, while the login screen only occurs at the beginning of the session (boot), and allows the user to pick a desktop environment. `gdm` (Gnome Desktop Manager) wasn't letting me choose, but `sddm` would.

Thus the solution was to run `systemctl disable gdm` and then `systemctl enable sddm`.